# Find linear transformation matrix from a linear transformation matrix of its composition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Since I am not yet very familiar with math vocabulary, I apologise if the terms used are not exactly correct. I am trying to understand more about linear transformations and ran into a problem I can't quite wrap my head around.

Let's say that $V$ is a vector space over the field $K$ and suppose we have a linear transformation $f \in \text{End}V$ thats matrix is know on some basis.

How to find a matrix of a linear transformation $g \in \text{End}V$ on the same basis, so that $g \circ g = f$.

For example if $V$ is vector space over the field $\mathbb{Z}_{11}$ and matrix of linear transformation $f\in \text{End}V$ on some basis is

\begin{pmatrix}
\bar{7} & \bar{3} & \bar{4} & \bar{0}\\
\bar{0} & \bar{6} & \bar{9} & \bar{6}\\
\bar{1} & \bar{9} & \bar{3} & \bar{1}\\
\bar{0} & \bar{2} & \bar{8} & \bar{5}\\
\end{pmatrix}

Find matrix of a linear transformation $g \in \text{End}V$ on the same basis, so that $g \circ g = f$.

At first I thought of diagonalising the matrix and find the square root of the elements, but I didn't get the answer that way so I don't know if it's a reasonable approach (I first transposed the matrix to be able to do linear tranformations on the rows of the matrix). This way I got elements that didn't have a square root in the field $\mathbb{Z}_{11}$.

I am grateful for any help I can get.

Comment: Could you provide a bit of context for this question? Why are you asking it? It seems as though you are assuming that there exists a transformation $g$ such that $g \circ g = f$ for **every** transformation $f$, but this is not the case.

Comment: If you're asking about how to find such a $g$ for transformations $f$ *such that there exists a $g$ for which $f = g \circ g$*, then I suspect the simplest approach is to use [Frobenius normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_normal_form). Have you heard of Frobenius normal form? Have you heard of Jordan canonical form?

Comment: For what it's worth, the characteristic polynomial of this matrix modulo $11$ is $(x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1)$. That leads to a nice trick that can be used to find a square root of the matrix *in this particular case*. Because $f^5 = I$, it follows that $(f^3)^2 = f$. So, we can simply take $g = f^3$.

Comment: In particular, this leads to the answer
$$
g = \left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 9 & 2 & 10 & 0 \\
 5 & 0 & 6 & 2 \\
 7 & 4 & 10 & 4 \\
 6 & 8 & 10 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Comment: This isn't always possible. It might be possible in this particular case so you might want to ask that for your transformation $f$. But for example, just like negative numbers don't have square roots over the reals, some matrices don't have "square roots". Take for example a diagonal matrix with negative entries

Comment: @FranciscoJoséLetterio The matrix $\pmatrix{-1&0\\0&-1}$ is diagonal with negative entries, but it has the matrix $\pmatrix{0&-1\\1&0}$ as a square root